# JAVA: How to calculate a point in 2d Space?

Tags: java, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to solve for the `X`, `Y` coordinates listed as `???`

All the variables that are available without the need of calculation.

The point in space at which the triangle rotates is static, the length and width are also static. But the rotation angle varies.

How can I solve the `???` coordinates?

[image: rotating a triangle]

Comment: let me google it for you: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/2d_transformation.htm . oh, -1 btw

Comment: Seems like a question for math.exchange, since this is not a code problem but a math problem.

Comment: First see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) then [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics))

Comment: Is it given that the triangle is a right-angled triangle? It seems not stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer to my question here:
http://mathhelpforum.com/trigonometry/255742-help-calculating-point-2d-space-rotating-right-angle-triangle.html#post883005

After which I created a simple java function to handle it all for me once given the proper Variables.

```
child.rotationPointY = (Width * (MathHelper.sin(-parent.rotateAngleX))) + (Height * (MathHelper.cos(-parent.rotateAngleX))) + parent.rotationPointY;
child.rotationPointZ = (Width * (MathHelper.cos(-parent.rotateAngleX))) - (Height * (MathHelper.sin(-parent.rotateAngleX))) + parent.rotationPointZ;
```

Thank you all